# pandas: filter out column values containing empty list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filter

I have the following data frame `my_df`:

```
col_A    col_B
---------------
John     []
Mary     ['A','B','C']
Ann      ['B','C']
```

I want to delete the rows where `col_B` has an empty list. i.e. I want the new data frame to be:

```
col_A    col_B
---------------
Mary     ['A','B','C']
Ann      ['B','C']
```

Below is what I did:

```
my_df[ len(my_df['col_B']) >0 ]
```

But I got the following errors:

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2133             try:
-> 2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4164)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4028)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13166)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13120)()

KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-75da0b0af6a1> in <module>()
----> 1 records_df_pair_count[ len(records_df_pair_count['stable_seq']) >0 ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2057             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2058         else:
-> 2059             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2060 
   2061     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2064         # get column
   2065         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2066             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2067 
   2068         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1384         res = cache.get(item)
   1385         if res is None:
-> 1386             values = self._data.get(item)
   1387             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1388             cache[item] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3539 
   3540             if not isnull(item):
-> 3541                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3542             else:
   3543                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2134                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2135             except KeyError:
-> 2136                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2137 
   2138         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4164)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4028)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13166)()

pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13120)()

KeyError: True
```

Any idea what I did wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way to do this:

```
my_df[my_df['col_b'].apply(lambda x: len(x)) > 0]
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [Series.str.len()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html) method:

```
my_df[my_df['col_B'].str.len() > 0]
```

Comment: For newer version of pandas (I'm on 1.0.3) the string for an empty list is '[]', thus length instead write: `my_df[my_df['col_B'].str.len() > 2]`

Answer (score 2):

You already got a couple answers that correct the problem. But I thought I'd chime in with an explanation of why yours doesn't work.

This gives a pandas series:

```
my_df['col_B']
```

So this gives the length of the series:

```
len(my_df['col_B'])
```

Since you have a non-empty series, this evaluates to True:

```
len(my_df['col_B']) >0
```

And this:

```
my_df[ len(my_df['col_B']) >0 ]
```

evaluates to:

```
my_df[True]
```

And clearly my_df is not going to have True as a column index. Hence the KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42964821/165753) can be further simplified:

`df[df.col.apply(len) > 0]`